# What is a three dimensional irrep ${\bf 3}$ of $SO(3)$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, vectors, group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations

1. What is three dimensional irreducible representation of $SO(3)$ denoted by ${\bf 3}$? Are they vectors or antisymmetric tensors of rank two each of them has three independent components.
2. Also when one writes $${\bf 3}\times{\bf 3}={\bf 1}+{\bf 3}+{\bf 5},$$ do they mean that there is no difference between the transformations of ${\bf 3}$ on the left and the ${\bf 3}$ on the right? In that case, is it true that an antisymmetric tensor transforming as $A^\prime_{ij}=R_{ik}R_{jl}A_{kl}$ can be reduced to $V^\prime_i=R_{ij}V_j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are the same: every real  antisymmetric tensor of rank 2 in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is one-to-one related with a real  vector with $3$ components and this association commutes with the corresponding action of $SO(3)$.

Comment: In that case, an antisymmetric tensor transforming as $A^\prime_{ij}=R_{ik}R_{jl}A_{kl}$ should be reducible to $V^\prime_i=R_{ij}V_j$?

Comment: Yes, use the $SO(3)$-invariant Ricci pseudotensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$ to prove it.

Comment: $V_i:= \epsilon_{ijk}A^{jk}$

Answer (score 0):

What is ${\bf 3}$?

One example is:

$$ Y_1^{\pm 1}(\mathbf {r}) \propto (x \pm iy)/r $$
$$ Y_1^0(\mathbf {r}) \propto z/r $$

which transform with the Wigner D-Matrix:

$${\displaystyle Y_{1 }^{m}({\mathbf {r} }')=\sum _{m'=-1 }^{1 }[D_{mm'}^{(1)}({\mathcal {R}})]^{*}Y_{1 }^{m'}({\mathbf {r} }),}$$

If you look at the 9 dyads:

$$ Y_{1 }^{m}({\mathbf {r} })Y_{1 }^{m'}({\mathbf {r} })$$

you can find 5 linear combinations, such as:

$$  Y_1^1(\mathbf {r}) Y_1^1(\mathbf {r}) \propto (x+iy)^2 \propto Y_2^2(\mathbf {r})$$

which transform as the $\bf 5$ dimensional representation. Another combination looks like $x^2+y^2+z^2$, which is scalar, and the remaining 3 transform like $\bf 3$, but look a little different, for example:

$$ Y_1^1(\mathbf {r}) Y_1^{-1}(\mathbf {r})- Y_1^{-1}(\mathbf {r}) Y_1^1(\mathbf {r})\propto x^2 + y^2 + i(-yx+xy) - [x^2 + y^2 +i(yx - xy)]$$
$$ = i(xy-yx)$$

transforms like $Y_1^0$.